# Usage Error during installation of Shopware 6

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I am currently getting an error while trying to install Shopware 6.

Looked everywhere around the internet but couldn't find a solution. The problem is when I run the shopware installer using XAMPP, during the configuration process it asks me about PHP Binary and I choose "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" after that when I try to choose a version and download Shopware 6, it gives me an error saying:

```
Usage: C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                                     [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                                     [-w] [-k start|restart|stop|shutdown] [-n service_name]
                                     [-k install|config|uninstall] [-n service_name]
                                     [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-T] [-S] [-X]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in  directives
  -d directory       : specify an alternate initial ServerRoot
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
  -C "directive"     : process directive before reading config files
  -c "directive"     : process directive after reading config files
  -n name            : set service name and use its ServerConfigFile and ServerRoot
  -k start           : tell Apache to start
  -k restart         : tell running Apache to do a graceful restart
  -k stop|shutdown   : tell running Apache to shutdown
  -k install         : install an Apache service
  -k config          : change startup Options of an Apache service
  -k uninstall       : uninstall an Apache service
  -w                 : hold open the console window on error
  -e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)
  -E file            : log startup errors to file
  -v                 : show version number
  -V                 : show compile settings
  -h                 : list available command line options (this page)
  -l                 : list compiled in modules
  -L                 : list available configuration directives
  -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS  : show parsed vhost settings
  -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG : show parsed run settings
  -S                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules 
  -M                 : a synonym for -t -D DUMP_MODULES
  -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES: show all included configuration files
  -t                 : run syntax check for config files
  -T                 : start without DocumentRoot(s) check
  -X                 : debug mode (only one worker, do not detach)
```

Did anyone encounter the same problem before? Can you guys recommend any solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that can't find a solution. I was using the wrong php file. It should've been: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" file.